# is there a name for security principle of "balance-preserving functions"? (e.g. for bank balances)

Tags: security-by-design

Suppose you are designing software to manage bank balances for different accounts belonging to a given customer.  A single customer can have multiple accounts with a bank, such as a credit card account, a checking account, and a savings account.  You know that there will be a large number of applications running on the bank's servers to perform certain functions, such as transferring a minimum fixed amount every month from the user's checking account to the savings account.

So, a naive approach would be to expose a function such as ChangeAccountBalance().  Then when your app moves money from the checking account to the savings account, you do:
ChangeAccountBalance(checking_account_id, -transfer_amount);
ChangeAccountBalance(checking_account_id, transfer_amount);

The problem with this API is that every app which can call ChangeAccountBalance() could increase a person's balance arbitrarily, so an insider could use this to bump up their own balance.  This means every app which has access to that API now has to be reviewed with the highest possible scrutiny to prevent this attack.

So instead, suppose your API exposes a function:
TransferBetweenSameCustomerAccounts(first_account_id, second_account_id, amount);
which fails if first_account_id and second_account_id do not belong to the same customer.

Now, if an insider gains control of an app which can call that function, they can longer put free money into their account.  So the apps which can call that API can be reviewed with a lower level of scrutiny because the incentive to attack them is much less.  (You would still need a function like TransferBetweenDifferentCustomerAccounts() to move money between different customers, and any app that has access to that function gets reviewed with the higher scrutiny level.)

Does this "balance-preserving" security principle have a name?  Where applications need an API so that they can transfer something of value between different data stores, so you design the API so that when you move something from one balance to another controlled by the same user, the API enforces that you cannot increase the balance in one place without decreasing it somewhere else?

Comment: I would call that an X/Y problem and security theater, honestly. Your goal is to keep administrators from stealing money... Your proposed solution doesn't address that, it only makes one method of them stealing a little more difficult.  You might want to have a very long talk with some accountants -- You'll probably find that their answer (and they've been working on this problem _far_ longer than digital computers have existed) is more along the lines of proper logging and audits...  And always do your books in ink.

Comment: Also, note that if you're doing something like distributing a mobile app that hits these APIs, the APIs are now public (even if you don't explicitly document them), and people can create whatever kind of application they want, and aren't going to bother to tell you.

Comment: Good catch, @Clockwork-Muse.  I missed where they said "app" and I was assuming that it was an internal API that sits inside of a properly secured network, not something that's accessible to the world like a mobile app would need to be. -- If it is exposed to a public network, the question shouldn't be if account A and B are linked, it's if the _authenticated_ user has _authorization_ to access accounts A and B.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yes I'm talking about an internal API.  I said "You know that there will be a large number of applications running on the bank's servers..." but I should have emphasized that more -- yes, these are internal "applications", not something running on the user's device.